# Grow a container while maintaining heights of the other containers in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have these three containers. That the first one needs to grow to cater for the children that will be in it. The second one could have a fixed height say a flex factor of 1, while the third one has a fixed height too say flex of 2. The whole of this screen can be scrollable. It actually has to be scrollable since the children of the first container can be a lot.
Note: the children of the first container will have a fixed height, the container will house a listview or column which will have fixed height children, say containers each of 50.0. How do I achieve this, especially the 'growability' of the first container, while maintaining the heights of the other containers.

What I have currently is

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.greenAccent[200],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.purpleAccent[200],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.orangeAccent[200],
                      )
                    ]),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  
                  color: Colors.redAccent[100],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  //height: 120.0,
                  color: Colors.redAccent[400],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Which just brings up lots and lots of errors, does not matter how I lay it out using flexibles and Expanded widgets. Again, I don't need the first container to scroll internally, it should grow according to the number of children in it, while the rest of the two containers maintain their heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not user `Expanded` or `Flexible` inside a scrollable widget since the child of `Expanded` will then get a height of infinity and the height of the child of `Flexible` will not get its parents height to compare with.

You can set the height of the bottom two containers based on the height of the screen.

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.greenAccent[200],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.purpleAccent[200],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100.0,
                      color: Colors.orangeAccent[200],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // 33 % of the screen height
                height: .33 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.redAccent[100],
              ),
              Container(
                // 33 % of the screen height
                height: .33 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.redAccent[400],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```